# br.read() is returning a wrong value

Tags: java

```
public class ConstructSkirt implements Fashion {

    int age;
    double FullLength,BottomRound,WaistRound;
    // these are the finall measurements after adding seam allownace
    double MFullLength,MBottomRound,MWaistRound;
    final int  fold=4;

    public void setMeasurements()
    {

        System.out.println("Measurements are set based on the age");

        try {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter the age of the person:");
            age=br.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switch(age)
        {
                    .
                    .
```

Here when I entered age as 10,it returned value 49 to age which resulted it to enter wrong code in switch case.

what is the reason for `br.read` to return wrong value.

Comment: I have also tried by using Integer.parseInt(br.read()) but it showed up error as output for br.read() is int and Integer.parseInt should have a String argument

Comment: It returned the correct value, you asked for the next character as an int and it returned 49 the code for '1'

Answer (score 4):

`BufferedReader#read()` returns, and I quote, "The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached".

It basically returns the code point of the one character read as `int`.

On a side note, you should try with a `Scanner`, it's more adequate to your purpose.

Quick & dirty example:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the age of the person:");
int age = s.nextInt();
System.out.printf("You typed %d%n", age);
s.close();
```

**I/O**

```
Enter the age of the person:123
You typed 123
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `br.readLine();` instead. It returns a `String`, not an `int`, and therefore you have to convert the returned value using the `Integer.parseInt()` method:

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better if you use Scanner for your program instead of BufferedReader

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.nextLine();
```